# ActionBar background only works in portrait mode

Tags: android

I have this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);



        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this,
                getSupportFragmentManager());
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.navbar_bg));
```

Why does the last line only work in portrait mode, in landscape mode no background is applied. I have not applied any custom orientation styles to the activity. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Tabs Design document](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html#stacked) and the [ActionBar Tabs guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs):

> the system adapts the action bar tabs for different screen sizes—placing them in the main action bar when the screen is sufficiently wide, or in a separate bar (known as the "stacked action bar") when the screen is too narrow

Therefore cases where the system decides to combine the bars (such as in landscape mode), the tabs will be part of the main Action Bar and share the same background as the Action Bar.

Comment: and you kind sir just made this clear to me. I failed to see it because I have hidden my actionbar so there was always only one bar, never thought it is action bar in landscape and stacked action bar in portrait. I will keep them in the stacked bar because this way you can scroll through. and by the way your last statement is wrong, portrait mode on 1280 tablet here. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nick - I've updated my answer to reflect that even larger devices can show stacked tabs.

Comment: Also that depends on how many tabs you have, generally speaking, they fit - they sit. have a nice day